# Apply function to dataframe (t-test)

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe with different conditions as rows and the respective means (m1, m2) for my groups as well as the standard deviations (s1, s2) as columns (n1 = 3, n2 = 21) I would like to apply this function to my dataframe:

```
t.test2 <- function(m1,m2,s1,s2,n1,n2,m0=0, equal.variance=FALSE)
{
  if( equal.variance==FALSE ) 
  {
    se <- sqrt( (s1^2/n1) + (s2^2/n2) )
    # welch-satterthwaite df
    df <- ( (s1^2/n1 + s2^2/n2)^2 )/( (s1^2/n1)^2/(n1-1) + (s2^2/n2)^2/(n2-1) )
  } else
  {
    # pooled standard deviation, scaled by the sample sizes
    se <- sqrt( (1/n1 + 1/n2) * ((n1-1)*s1^2 + (n2-1)*s2^2)/(n1+n2-2) ) 
    df <- n1+n2-2
  }      
  t <- (m1-m2-m0)/se 
  dat <- data.frame(rbind(c(m1-m2, se, t, 2*pt(-abs(t),df))))   
  colnames(dat) <- c("Difference of means", "Std Error", "t", "p-value")
  return(dat) 
}
```

When I try to use the function like this:

```
t.test2(t_test[,3], t_test[,4], t_test[,5], t_test[,6], 3, 21)
```

I get an error message.

When I try

```
t.test2(t_test$m1, t_test$m2, t_test$s1, t_test$s2, 3, 21)
```

I get a bunch of "NA"s in return.

So far I only managed to apply it either when I call the function on the values directly (one row at a time) or when I have a dataframe with only one row. As my dataframe contains more than 400 rows, I would really like to be able to use the t test function directly on that dataframe. Ideally, the output of the function would be bound to my original dataframe. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you give an example of the dataframe that contains your values?

Comment: Hi Onyambu, my dataframe looked almost exactly like the one Edward posted below:

`t_test <- data.frame(sequence_number=c("abc_1", "cde_2", "def_3"), concentration=c(1,1,1), m1=c(2,3,10), m2=c(3,4,20), s1=c(4,2,1), s2=c(1,2,1)); t_test`
`

I had initially grouped my first and second column, that is why Edwards solution did not work immediately. After removing the grouping it works!

Answer (score 2):

Use `cbind` instead of `c` to create the final data frame. And there's no need to use `rbind`. In fact, you can just use `data.frame` since all the values are vectorized.

```
t.test2 <- function(m1,m2,s1,s2,n1,n2,m0=0, equal.variance=FALSE)
{
   ...
   dat <- data.frame(m1-m2, se, t, 2*pt(-abs(t),df))
   ...
}

t_test <- data.frame(id=1:3, v2=c(1,1,1), m1=c(2,3,10), m2=c(3,4,20), 
                     s1=c(4,2,1), s2=c(1,2,1)); t_test

#  id v2 m1 m2 s1 s2
#1  1  1  2  3  4  1
#2  2  1  3  4  2  2
#3  3  1 10 20  1  1

t.test2(t_test[,3], t_test[,4], t_test[,5], t_test[,6], 3, 21)
#      Difference of means Std Error           t     p-value
#1                  -1 2.3196880  -0.4310925 0.707763289
#2                  -1 1.2344268  -0.8100926 0.485221636
#3                 -10 0.6172134 -16.2018517 0.001091188

t.test2(t_test$m1, t_test$m2, t_test$s1, t_test$s2, 3, 21)
#  Difference of means Std Error           t     p-value
#1                  -1 2.3196880  -0.4310925 0.707763289
#2                  -1 1.2344268  -0.8100926 0.485221636
#3                 -10 0.6172134 -16.2018517 0.001091188
```

Comment: Thanks so much Edward! That solved my problem! Initially it did not work because I had grouped some of my variables but now after removing the grouping it works perfectly fine!